# Can you splice #8 stranded ground with #10 solid ground?

Tags: electrical, wiring, conduit

I'm attempting to connect a relatively small electric water heater in my pole barn. It requires a 60amp breaker, so my plan was to run 6/3 NM from the main panel (only required 6/2 but I decided to just get the 6/3 in case the next owner wanted to do something different) through the attic to the other side of the building (pole barn garage), come down through the ceiling and down the wall a few inches, and splice/convert to MC inside a massive junction box that is already connected to a piece of unistrut up near the ceiling -- primarily so I don't have exposed NM running 4-5 feet down the wall to the disconnect.

Once the splice from the 6/3 NM to the MC cable was made inside the junction, it would go from the junction box as MC to the disconnect switch, where it would then go to the water heater itself. In retrospect, I should have just run 6/3 MC from the main panel, through the attic, and directly to the disconnect. I wanted to save money with 6/3 NM for most of the run and here I am.

The problem I'm encountering is that the 6/3 NM from the electrical supply house came with 10awg solid copper ground, and 6awg stranded conductors. The 6/3 MC cable I ordered from an online supply house (local only had rolls of 500'+) has 6awg stranded conductors and 8awg stranded ground according to the person I talked to. It is my understanding (I could be mistaken) that you should not splice different-sized wires together.

Is it safe/to code to splice 10awg solid copper ground to 8awg stranded copper ground? If not, is there any solution other than running 6/3 MC from the main panel all the way to the disconnect switch? I've already run the 6/3 NM through the attic, secured it at proper intervals, etc. so ideally I would love not to have to take it all down.

EDIT: Wanted to add this is a 11kW water heater, solely to heat water for a reverse osmosis system to get the stated GPD rate. The stated GPD rate assumes 65 PSI inlet, 77F water, no more than 500ppm. The correction factor is .52 if you have 50F inlet water, which I do from my well.

Also, I have completely separate service to my pole barn (different transformer, meter, panels, etc.) than my house, and have done load calcs and have the room for 60amps without a problem.

Comment: Wow. One of the best written, most clear electrical wiring questions we've had in quite a while. Well done!

Answer (score 7):

Nothing wrong with splicing different size wires. You'll want to ground the "massive junction box" so I'd just mount a dual ground lug in the box and connect your two ground wires to it.

Answer (score 5):

It is quite common to splice different wire gauges together, if they are at or above the minimum for the breaker.

You cannot splice 14 gauge to 12 gauge on a 20 amp breaker, but you can on a 15 amp breaker.

You will not have a problem if use the proper size wire nut.

It seems that the two building are attached. NM cannot be used outside in wet conditions(outside is wet).

The only time ground splices give a problem is with the ground wire from the panel to ground rods. You'll need special non removable splices.

Answer (score 5):

### Correcting a few misconceptions

> I'm attempting to connect a relatively small electric water heater

A standard full-house 20-50 gallon **tanked** water heater is 4500W and takes a 25A breaker (typically used with a 30A breaker).

So unless you are confusing a 2-pole 30A for a "60", a 60A heater is actually rather large.  Are you sure your pole barn has the feeder ampacity for that?  Are you sure your house has the spare service ampacity to add a 60A load?  You need to do a NEC Article 220 Load Calculation on both.

> It requires a 60amp breaker, so my plan was to run 6/3 NM from the main panel

That's a problem. #6 NM-B is only 55A wire. See for yourself: Copper, left column.  #6 NM, UF, TW = 55A.

[image]

*Note that there is no such thing as 60A wire. Why do manufacturers have trouble receiving this memo?*

For why NM is in the 60C column, see NEC 334.80.

> come down through the ceiling and down the wall a few inches, and splice/convert to MC inside a massive junction box that is already connected to a piece of unistrut up near the ceiling -- primarily so I don't have exposed NM running 4-5 feet down the wall to the disconnect.

A simpler way of doing that is to use a stick of *literally any kind of metal pipe* into a junction box. Some have been known to use electrical conduit, which fits neatly onto junction boxes (but then, so does pipe if the box is threaded).

> I wanted to save money with 6/3 NM for most of the run and here I am.

And here you are.  Now you'll need to either figure out the heater is actually 30A, or see if you can derate that heater to 55A (not likely).  Another option is to go with a *tanked* heater which are typically 4500W or 3800W for the mobile home models.  They're insulated quite well; just the same, in my shop I use a wind-down timer switch such as an Intermatic SW12HWK.

It seems like you "blindly" overbuild instead of do research, and that's how the #6 NM error snuck in there.  I would flip that around: research then wisely overbuild e.g. I'm all for the /3 thing.

> Once the splice from the 6/3 NM to the MC cable was made inside the junction, it would go from the junction box as MC to the disconnect switch, where it would then go to the water heater itself.

The disconnect can be avoided by permanently installing a factory approved "locking kit" on the circuit breaker.  This clips onto the breaker and provides a hole in the right place to use a lock to prevent handle movement.  The purpose of both the lock and the disconnect is maintenance lockout/tagout; either will suffice.

*On the other hand, the disconnect is a great place to splice from aluminum to copper wire*.  Nothing wrong with aluminum at large sizes; it's proven safe because it's on lugs rated for aluminum (typically made *of* aluminum) and it is torqued to spec with a torque driver (which must be done on ALL terminals by the way).

### So what about dissimilar size splices?

> It is my understanding (I could be mistaken) that you should not splice different-sized wires together.

There's no problem with that, as long as the connecting device is listed/rated for that.

> I've already run the 6/3 NM through the attic, secured it at proper intervals, etc. so ideally I would love not to have to take it all down.

Leave it in the sky for some future application which does not exceed 55A.  Such as 50A EV charging (the EV companies didn't get the memo either).

Comment: How much you want to bet it is a small **tankless**. In a quick search, I found 14.4kw == 60A x 240V gets you 2.93 GPM. So small relative to a whole house, but fine for a sink or two in a barn. And a crazy waste when you can just get a small tank and use the usual 4500W/25-30A etc.

Comment: Does 240.4(B) allow the 55A ampacity of #6 NM-B to be "rounded up" to the next-higher standard breaker value and be protected by a 60A breaker? (if not, then why not?)

Comment: @GregHill 240.4(B) says the **ampacity** cannot be "rounded up". When a 60A breaker is used because standard sizes don't cover 55A, nothing else changes.  The Load Calculation on the branch circuit or feeder **still** cannot 55A.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gp4SyoB5D5s esp. at 2:55.

Comment: OP added useful details - it **is** a tankless (I knew it!) at 11kW = 46A @ 240V. Which is *interesting*. Because without a continuous derate, it should only need 50A breaker. But with a continuous derate it needs 46 x 1.25 = 57.5A. Which makes me think the calculation is 11kW = 44A @ 250V. Which x 1.25 = exactly 55A! Which meets the NM 6 AWG limit *and* gets a 60A breaker. Mystery solved *and* cable is OK.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the detailed reply. It's only an 11kW water heater, solely to heat water to 80F (the lowest temp it can even heat at) before a reverse osmosis system (it requires 65psi, 77F, and 500ppm or less water to get the correct GPD.) I have completely separate service (diff. meter, transformer, panels, etc.) for my pole barn with plenty of room to add the 60amps while staying within 80% rule.

Would my only solution be to re-run the entire thing with 4/3, if the heater requires a 60amp breaker and the 6/3 only can do 55amps? The manual for the heater says the max load is 54 amps

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact Hey, thanks for your response too. Here's the specs from the manufacturer for my particular unit. https://www.ecosmartus.com/product/ecosmart-ECO-11-13-kW-Electric-Tankless-Water-Heater

I hope you are correct (I surely thought I was before I ordered everything so fingers crossed). I knew I had gone off the manual/specs to figure out what I needed, but like Harper-ReinstateMonica noted, I *did* come across the same info about 6awg only doing 55amps, and it made me start doubting my clearly non-electrician self.

Comment: Correction based on the spec sheet. They're rating it at 11kW @ 220V yet coming up with 54A. Not sure how...Ohm's law calculator...here we go: 11kW @ 220V means 4.4 Ohms and 50A. Bump it up to 240V and you get 13kW and 54A. So no continuous derate (that would put it over 60A (whether starting at 50A or 54A), so that means they're properly rating it for 6 AWG NM at 55A max. (just squeak by) and the 60A breaker is *breaker only* not actual usage. And life is good.

Comment: The way to look at from a user/installer standpoint is: Device needs 'x' Amps. I need 'y' wire to support that. I need a breaker which protects to a level of 'x' Amps to match the wire rating. Oops, 'x' breaker is not available (generally, not talking about supply shortage issues - those do not exempt code, usually) so I can round up to the next size breaker but am on Scout's Honor to stick to the 'x' current. x = 55 (54 and a fraction == 55), y = 6 AWG NM, round breaker to 60.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the clarification! From reading the other replies re: splicing different ground wire sizes (8awg stranded and 10awg solid), it sounds like I'm good to go doing so as long as my connector (this here: https://www.alliedelec.com/m/d/3e029c04708914d2a3e4d297d6791c41.pdf) supports it, which it seems to do? I need/want the 3 port so I can ground to the metal junction box, and then continue with the ground to the disconnect switch. This is the only 3 #6 connector they had at either of the local electrical supply houses. I want to say I love this community, very helpful and welcoming

Comment: That gadget, at least based on the specs, doesn't support solid copper (which is odd) and looks like its primary goal is to let you combine aluminum and copper. Which is a very good thing if you need it. But they are very expensive - a quick search shows $30 or more! Crazy! But for a pair of small copper wires, one solid, one stranded, just use a standard Ideal (or similar) wire nut - trivial and inexpensive. Or if you really don't like wire nuts, a Wago will do just fine as well. Both an ordinary wire nut or a Wago lever nut should cost < $ 1 each though you usually buy in multi-packs.

Comment: Example from Home Depot: 30-pack of assorted wire nuts https://www.homedepot.com/p/Commercial-Electric-Winged-Wire-Connector-Assortment-30-Pack-EWA-30/315849536 $5.98.

Comment: @ShunsukeSengoku "*only* an 11kW" is huge.  All tankless are huge.  If the unit is actually 55A (and that sounds about right given the kW) then yes, it probably is a 54A unit, and perhaps the manufacturer *did* get the memo.    If it's UL listed and the instructions (not brochure) say 6 AWG NM,  then you are all set.

Comment: @manassehkatz solid wire is not permitted in NEC above #10, except for grounds.

Comment: I know. The whole question started with **#10 solid** + **#8 stranded**. That expensive gadget says in the spec sheet: AL 8 - 4, CU Solid N/A, CU Stranded 14 - 4. So aside from the crazy cost when a wire nut or Wago will do just fine, it won't for the (legitimate) #10 solid.

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact I was not able to locate a connector that would allow (3) #6 wires. Am I wrong that to connect the NM ground to the ground screw in the junction box, and then continue into the MC, I would need 3 ports? The incoming "main ground" (from NM) going into the connector, the 2nd port going out and around the ground screw, and then the 3rd port going into the MC to the disconnect switch? I found Ideal 454 Blue that supports (2) #6, which I am going to use for the "hot" conductors. Either way, I already bought (1) of the see-through connectors I linked above.

Comment: Ok, sorry it's too early in the morning and my brain isn't firing on all cylinders yet. I realized I don't actually HAVE #6 *grounds*, so I don't need to support (3) #6's. I'll check the specs for my wire nuts and see if they can support (1-2) #10 and (1) #8.

Comment: @ShunsukeSengoku Shouldn't be a problem. But even if it was, you can drill and tap as many #10-32 holes in the steel box as you need for additional ground screws.  Don't put em on knockouts.  10-32 takes a #7 hole which is slightly larger than 1/8", so I drill 1/8" holes with cheap bits, then widen with the #7 drill (to conserve its life) then tap. Pre-COVID the tap, #7 bit and tap handle was under $10 together.